# Best way to turn off switching regulator and conserve power

Tags: current, voltage-regulator, switching-regulator

I am trying to figure out one of two ways to switch off the power in my circuit using an LM2596-5.0 switching regulator.

Option 1: In the datasheet it says you can pull the regulator ON/OFF pin to VCC to turn it off, with a loss of 80uA.

I'm using an SPDT switch, so if I choose the above option, the regular's input capacitor will remain charged, and won't the battery drain?

Option 2 is a more traditional way, leave the regulator ON/OFF pin tied to ground (datasheet says this will turn the regulator on), and the SPDT switches all of the power to the circuit, which charges the capacitor up and I'm sure eventually this might wear out the switch's contacts, despite it being rated for 5 Amps. The circuit consumes less than 50mA average, but I'm assuming that capacitor wants to charge quickly, hence my concern.

In either Option 1 or 2, I'm avoiding a parasitic loss on a voltage divider as shown in my schematic. Option 2 would avoid the 80uA loss if I use the regulator's shutdown feature, but in my application I don't need to worry about 80uA loss.

I see in the datasheet for the LM2596 that if I choose my Option 1 it would truly be a 'soft' start, which would extend the switch life? (not really an issue I'm thinking, due to the switch's rating, but I may be wrong?)

Can someone help me decide what would work best? Thank you.

BVCC is battery voltage which is connected to the common/center pin of the SPDT switch, the top pin of the switch is connected to the common/center pin when the switch actuator points downwards.

1st schematic showing Option 1:

[image]

1nd schematic showing Option 2:

[image]

Comment: *so if I choose the above method, the regular's input capacitor will remain charged, and won't the battery drain?* No, not if you use a decent capacitor there. A 680 uF cap should leak **much less** than the 80uA of the LM2596.

Comment: If the toggle switch can handle the current then I see no reason not to go for the simplest which is option 2. And you avoid that 80uA which may not be a problem but I'd avoid it anyway.

Comment: The capacitor would be a 35V Panasonic FK V series, pretty good quality I think.

Comment: @FakeMoustache how will the capacitor affect the switch's contacts? Or will it not at all?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how much current will flow when the switch is toggled on for the capacitor to charge, arcing the contacts.

Comment: A good switch can handle the inrush current from the capacitor. What switch are you using ? Even if the power source can deliver a lot of current then the series resistances here and there limit the inrush current. In general, I expect no problems with such a design.

Comment: @FakeMoustache You seem convinced about that much less for capacitor leakage, but for upwards of 500uF one or more uA per volt would not at all surprise me. There's plenty types I'd see leak 100uA at 30V or even more.

Comment: If you don't care about the 80 uA loss then what is your question about really?

Comment: What kind of comment is that? Plenty was stated in my question about concern with switch life, and asking if the regulator is soft-start or not. I already found out the regulator is soft-start in the datasheet just now.

Comment: @FakeMoustache The switch I'm using's datasheet: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/140/100-346274.pdf `5 Amps with resistive load @ 120VAC or 28VDC` My battery is 12V nominal.

Comment: @aviatorken89 you said "I don't need to worry about 80uA loss". If this is true then go for the soft shut down feature. The 680 uF capacitor might take a hundred microamps so choose one that is low leakage.

Comment: Looks like a switch which can handle this fine. In case of doubt use the one with 2 switches (so 2 x 3 = 6 contacts) and connect both switches in parallel. Then you double the current the contacts can handle. But even one contact should handle this fine.

Comment: You can put a 3 Ohm resistor in series with your switch. This will limit inrush to less than 5A. 50 mA * 3 Ohms = 150 mV. I am not sure if 50mA was the input or output current. If it is the output current, then the situation will be even better. If you don't like the 150 mV drop, you can add PMOS in parallel with the resistor, and turn it on with the regulator output.